# Apex Class Variable placement

Tags: apex, unit-test

I was creating a Test Class and my Test class states that the variable is not defined:

```
Global class ContractUpdateContractRenewalStartDate implements Schedulable
{     
       global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)

       {
        Date **contractdate** = System.today().addDays(-1);

        list<Contract> Contractupdate = [SELECT Id, Contract_Start_Date_Current__c,Contract_End_Date_Current__c FROM Contract WHERE Automatic_renewal__c = TRUE AND Contract_End_Date_Current__c =: contractdate ];

            for(Contract c: Contractupdate)
                {
                        c.Contract_Start_Date_Current__c = System.today();
                        update Contractupdate ;
                } 
    }


 }
```

Test:

```
@isTest
private class TestContractorUpdateStartDate {

     static testMethod void TestContractorUpdateStartDate()
  {
    ContractUpdateContractRenewalStartDate.**contractdate**(System.today());
  }
}
```

Am I setting the `contractdate` variable in the wrong place in my original code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to schedule your job in the test method, and it'll set the value for you:

```
@isTest class TestContractorUpdateStartDate {
    @isTest static void TestContractorUpdateStartDate() {
        Test.startTest();
        System.schedule('Test Job', '0 0 0 ? * *',
            new ContractUpdateContractRenewalStartDate());
        Test.stopTest();
        // Your scheduled job has now run.
    }
}
```

If you *need* to set the date for purposes of testing (e.g. your filtered field is actually a formula), then you can make a class-level variable:

```
Global class ContractUpdateContractRenewalStartDate implements Schedulable {
    // Allow tests to see the variable, but not "normal" code
    @TestVisible Date contractdate = System.today().addDays(-1);
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        list<Contract> Contractupdate = [SELECT Id, Contract_Start_Date_Current__c,Contract_End_Date_Current__c FROM Contract WHERE Automatic_renewal__c = TRUE AND Contract_End_Date_Current__c =: contractdate ];
        for(Contract c: Contractupdate) {
            c.Contract_Start_Date_Current__c = System.today();
        }
        update Contractupdate;
    } 
}
```

Note also that I moved the DML statement outside the for loop-- your code will start crashing if the query is too large.

If you go with @TestVisible, you can set it after creating the object in memory:

```
@isTest class TestContractorUpdateStartDate {
    @isTest static void TestContractorUpdateStartDate() {
        Test.startTest();
        ContractUpdateContractRenewalStartDate updater = new ContractUpdateContractRenewalStartDate();
        updater.contractdate = System.today();
        System.schedule('Test Job', '0 0 0 ? * *',
            updater);
        Test.stopTest();
        // Your scheduled job has now run.
    }
}
```

Finally, if you're looking to actually get full code coverage, remember to create records in your unit test first:

```
@isTest class TestContractorUpdateStartDate {
    @isTest static void TestContractorUpdateStartDate() {
        // Create some records for your test to use here
        // They will not persist to the database after the test ends
        Test.startTest();
```

Comment: Back for more guidance:  I have created a Test Method that calls a Test Utility method but my coverage is still low.  So if I could get another set of eyes on the code that would be great.  Here is my class that is suppose to create a test account and associated Contracts:

Comment: @isTest
public class TestContractDataFactory {
    public static void createTestRecords(Integer numAccts, Integer numContractsPerAcct) {
        List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();  
        for(Integer i=0;i<numAccts;i++) {
            Account a = new Account(Name='TestAccount' + i);
            accts.add(a);
        }
        insert accts;

Comment: List<Contract> cons = new List<Contract>();
        for (Integer j=0;j<numAccts;j++) 
        {
             Account acct = accts[j];
          {
                cons.add(new Contract(StartDate=System.today().addDays(-1),
                Status='Request',
                AccountId=acct.Id));
            }
        }
        // Insert all contracts for the account
        insert cons;
    }
}

Comment: Here is the Class that calls the utility:                                                              @isTest
private class TestContractUpdateStartDateWithData {
    static testmethod void test1() {
        TestContractDataFactory.createTestRecords(1,5);
    }
}

Comment: Here is my Class based on suggestion:  Global class ContractUpdateContractRenewalStartDate implements Schedulable
    {     
       @TestVisible Date contractdate = System.today().addDays(-1);
        global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) 
            {
list<Contract> Contractupdate = [SELECT Id, Contract_Start_Date_Current__c,Contract_End_Date_Current__c FROM Contract WHERE Automatic_renewal__c = TRUE AND Contract_End_Date_Current__c =: contractdate ];
  for(Contract c: Contractupdate) 
  {
       c.Contract_Start_Date_Current__c = System.today();
}update Contractupdate;
            }  }

Comment: Also, why is my code formatted together when I post it? Thanks

Comment: @Michael Comments only support basic formatting, as they're not intended to be full questions or answers. Technically, you probably should have created a new question. However, give me a few minutes and I'll see if I can offer any advice.

Comment: @Michael I don't know your system too well, but I'd guess that either Automatic_Renewal__c isn't true or Contract_End_Date_Current__c isn't the right date. Looking at your factory class, I don't see these two fields being set, so if you're expecting them to be set from a trigger or workflow, they're not. Make sure your data is correctly built.

Comment: like I said.  Just needed another set of eyes.  You are correct.  I needed to set the Automatic_Renewal__c to True.  My issue is that the Contract_End_Date_Current__c is a formula field based Contract Start Date and terms.  I will have to figure that out.  Also, when I set the values in the Factory Class do I have to use the prefix con.field or can I just  reference the field?  Thank you for your patience and help.....

Comment: sfdcfox, is there a way to display the test results(account, contracts) created from the Test Class? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, not the values I am setting in the Factory but the Contract_End_Date_Current__c that is based on the start date and terms.  I am populating the start date and terms.  I was not sure if I could perform a select in the Class to see the results.

Comment: @Michael yes, you could run a query and debug it (then check your logs), or you could even use System.assert methods to make sure that the values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: sfdcfox, looking at the logs I see the date values being return are date/time.  Could this be an issue if my Date values should be 05/02/2016?  Can you format the date value if you are using the addDays method? Thanks for your help......M

Comment: @Michael Date values debug as dates with a time of 0:00:00. That has nothing to do with whatever problem you're having. You need to set the right dates to satisfy your formula. I'm guessing the start date needs to be further in the past.

Comment: @sfdfox thank you for the reply.  So omitting the time the date result is formatted like this 2016-05-02 but in Saleforce it looks like this: 05/02/2016.  Is this an issue.

Comment: Ok.  I finally got my assertion to run successfully:                                   Datetime yourDate = DATE.today().addDays(-1);
System.assertEquals(yourDate,Contracts.Contract_End_Date_Current__c                     So the yourDate Variable should be the same as what is in my Class @TestVisible Date contractdate = DATE.today().addDays(-1);  Am I not comparing the date values correctly in the ContractUpdateContractRenewalStartDate Class?  I have to be making this harder than it needs to be.  Thanks again for your time and patience.  M

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you are trying to call `contractdate` as a method from your test, rather than a variable.

```
MyClass.contractDate(value); // method
MyClass.contractDate = value; // assignment
```

Secondly, you are declaring the variable with the scope of the method. You need to declare it at the class level and make it `static` if you want to be able to assign it in a test. I recommend leaving it `private` so that other classes (aside from test classes) cannot muck with it. For example:

```
global class MySchedulable implements Schedulable
{
    @TestVisible private static Date contractdate = Date.today().addDays(-1);
    global void execute(SchedulableContext context)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

static testMethod void myTest()
{
    MySchedulable.contractdate = Date.today();
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can make the variable stateful if you prefer.

```
global class MySchedulable implements Schedulable
{
    @TestVisible private Date contractdate = Date.today().addDays(-1);
    global void execute(SchedulableContext context)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

static testMethod void myTest()
{
    MySchedulable instance = new MySchedulable();
    instance.contractdate = Date.today();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle this is:

```
global class ContractUpdateContractRenewalStartDate implements Schedulable
{ 
    @TestVisible private Date contractdate = System.today().addDays(-1);

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        list<Contract> Contractupdate = [SELECT Id, Contract_Start_Date_Current__c,Contract_End_Date_Current__c FROM Contract WHERE Automatic_renewal__c = TRUE AND Contract_End_Date_Current__c =: contractdate ];
        ...
    }
}
```

and then in the test:

```
@isTest
private class TestContractorUpdateStartDate {
    static testMethod void TestContractorUpdateStartDate()
    {
        ContractUpdateContractRenewalStartDate schedulable = new ContractUpdateContractRenewalStartDate();
        schedulable.contractdate = System.today();
        ...
    }
}
```

as this indicates that you only want to change the `contractdate`to allow a test to work.

Comment: Hmm, I reasoned at first that it *had* to be static, but I guess that way just feels cleaner to me.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Non-static feels more right to me but given that the scheduler only creates one instance per transaction static should work too. Not even sure if more than one instance can be scheduled in a test but of it can again non-static is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.  Code is error free.  Coverage is pretty low but I will try to figure something out.  Thanks again for your explanations.